# Models of $\mathsf{ZF^-_2}$ over $\mathsf{ZF}$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Let $\mathsf{ZF^-_2}$ be a second-order ZF without Powerset, and the second-order Collection in place of Replacement. It is easy to see that every transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF^-_2}$ is closed under subsets of its elements.

Moreover, we can show in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that every transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF^-_2}$ is $H_\kappa$ for some regular $\kappa$:

> *Proof.* Let $\kappa=\sup\{|x|:x\in A\}$, then $A\subseteq H_\kappa$. By second-order Replacement with the induction, we have $\alpha\in H_\kappa$ if $\alpha<\kappa$. Applying second-order separation, we can see that $A$ and $H_\kappa$ agrees on its sets of ordinals. Hence $A=H_\kappa$.

My question is:

> Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $A$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF^-_2}$, but $A\neq H_\kappa$ for any cardinal $\kappa$?

Since the notion $H_\kappa$ is not unique in the choiceless setting, the answer could depend on the formulation of $H_\kappa$. (I know there are at least two definitions of it: one of them is that of [Aspero and Karagila](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04077), and the other one is that of [Lubarsky and Rathjen](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.200310054).)

Note that, Lubarsky and Rathjen proved the following: if $A$ is a transitive set such that $2\in A$ and $A$ satisfies Union and second-order Replacement, then the ordinal
$$o(A) = \min\{\alpha\mid\alpha\notin A\}$$
is regular. (Lemma 2.4 of Lubarsky and Rathjen.) Hence the following strategy does not work: construct a model that thinks every cardinal is singular but there is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF^-_2}$.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Apparently there's also one due to Randall Holmes, for which $H_\kappa$ would contain only well orderable sets; but presumably $H_{V_\kappa}$ might work. And there's Gabe Goldberg's definition, but that one is a bit like Holmes' when using $V_\kappa$ instead of $\kappa$, I think, but probably not really the same.

Comment: @Asaf Holmes' definition could be the same as that of Lubarsky and Rathjen up to some modifications (like replacing $<\kappa$ to $\kappa$), as both of them refer to the same Jech's paper (but I do not check it yet.) Also, I wonder how I can find Goldberg's definition.

Comment: He mentioned it in his Bristol-Oxford talk. $H_\kappa$ is the union of all transitive sets which are the image of $V_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\kappa$. I think this one works better in the context of large cardinals, though.

Comment: I don't understand myself why I don't remember it, although I also took this talk.

Comment: It was mentioned at the end, during the questions part.

Comment: I suppose the natural line of reasoning is to show that models of $\sf ZF_2^-$ are closed under Lindenbaum numbers, as a start.

Comment: Looking at the Lubarsky–Rathjen definition, it seems that their $H(V_\kappa)$ is the same as Goldberg's $H_\kappa$.